# IFERROR or Skipping #NA's in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

So I have this code below, but I want to leave any cell that comes up with
"#N/A" as a blank value.

```
Range("R2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=INDEX(Detail!C[-17]:C[-17],MATCH(C[-16]&""D&O"",Detail!C[-14]:C[-14],0),1)"
Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("R2:R" & lastrow)
```

I know that I can fix that when I type directly in the cell by using =IFERROR(INDEX(Detail!A:A,MATCH(B:B&"D&O",Detail!D:D,0),1),""), but I want it to automatically populate the whole column through VBA, and if I use IFERROR in the VBA I get a Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error.

Any ideas on how I can update my code to populate the #NA's as blank cells?

Comment: In VBA, are you properly doing the quotes? `"=IFERROR(INDEX(Detail!C[-17]:C[-17],MATCH(C[-16]&""D&O"",Detail!C[-14]:C[-14],0),1),"""")"`  Also, make sure you have a worksheet (in the current workbook) called `Detail`.

Comment: I just copied and pasted what you put and still got the same error. And I do have the Detail worksheet in the current workbook. So all of the cells I'm supposed to get values, I do, but I would like to get rid of the #N/A in the other cells to just leave it blank when I know I am not supposed to get any values.

Comment: Is that intended to be an array formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, this could be considerably simplified by changing it to:

```
Range("R2:R" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = _ 
"=IFERROR(INDEX(Detail!C[-17]:C[-17],MATCH(C[-16]&""D&O"",Detail!C[-14]:C[-14],0),1),"""")"
```

No need to .Select and then .AutoFill to your range. Also, from the body of your question, it looks like you didn't double-quote your double-quotes (4 consecutive double-quotes).

This worked just fine for me.

Comment: Ugh, yup. I hate when it's something little like that I overlook. Thank you very much! Problem solved.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you! It is very appreciated for users to "Accept" an answer that works for them, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(Detail!C[-17]:C[-17],MATCH(C[-16]&""D&O"",Detail!C[-14]:C[-14],0),1),""Error"")"
```